# Proptypes: Verify an array of interface as props in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-proptypes

I have some troubles on a react component and I would need some help for a solution...

I want to use propTypes on my component in order to have a runtime verification. I have implemented interfaces for the props I want to use. Some of the props are arrays of interfaces. Here is what I have so far:

**Definition of types:**

```js
   export type Point = {
    /** x value */
    readonly x: number;

    /** y value */
    readonly y: number;
  }

  /** Contains information relative to a line plot */
  export interface LineData {
    /** name of the line. Will be used in legend */
    readonly legend: string;

    /** Color of the line. If unspecified, a color will be chosen automatically */
    color?: string;

    /** width of the line in pixel. If not specified, a default value is provided */
    strokeWidth?: number;

    /** Contains all points associated with this line */
    readonly data: Array<Point>;
  }

  /** Graph properties */
  export interface GraphProps {
    /** An array that contains all line definitions */
    readonly lineDatas: Array<LineData>;

    /** The plot's title. Is set in upper left corner of the plot, outside border */
    readonly plotTitle?: string;

    /** Plot title's font size */
    readonly plotTitleFontSize?: number;
  }
```

**Implementation of Proptypes:**

```js
Graph.propTypes = {  
  lineDatas: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
    legend : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    color:PropTypes.string,
    strokeWidth: PropTypes.number,
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.shape({
      x: PropTypes.number,
      y: PropTypes.number
    }))
  })),
  plotTitle: PropTypes.string,
  plotTitleFontSize: PropTypes.number,
};
```

I get this error, even though egend is set as required...

```
Property 'legend' is optional in type 'InferProps<{ legend: Requireable<string>; color: Requireable<string>; strokeWidth: Requireable<number>; data: Requireable<InferProps<{ x: Requireable<number>; y: Requireable<...>; }>[]>; }>' but required in type 'LineData'.
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Shouldn't you add a `.isRequired` to the `lineData` filed's `PropTypes.arrayOf()` ? And the same for the `data` field?

Comment: yes, I should indeed, but the error still remains after that.

Comment: Did you try `PropTypes.exact()` instead of `PropTypes.shape()` ?

Comment: Looks like the PropTypes.exact was the right solution, thanks a million!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posting my comments as an answer.

You should use `PropTypes.exact()` instead of `PropTypes.shape()` and also add some missing `.isRequired` calls to `lineData` and `data` fields.

The prototypes code would be:

```
Graph.propTypes = {  
  lineDatas: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.exact({
    legend : PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    color:PropTypes.string,
    strokeWidth: PropTypes.number,
    data: PropTypes.arrayOf(PropTypes.exact({
      x: PropTypes.number,
      y: PropTypes.number
    })).isRequired
  })).isRequired,
  plotTitle: PropTypes.string,
  plotTitleFontSize: PropTypes.number,
};
```